# Automatonyous state machine, generate graph from code

Tags: c#, .net, automatonymous

I'm using Automatonyous state machines in my c# project. 
I'm wondering if there is a way to automatic obtain the graph of coded state machines.

Comment: https://github.com/MassTransit/Automatonymous/tree/master/src/Automatonymous/Graphing ??

Comment: Yes, it seems that this code could generate an object representing the state machine graph. Now, for me, the question is: does exist an example that explain how to use this object representing the state machine graph to obtain a drawing of this graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a GraphViz .dot file from the state machine using the Visualizer assembly.

https://github.com/MassTransit/Automatonymous/blob/master/src/Automatonymous.Tests/Visualizer_Specs.cs#L30

### UPDATE

With MassTransit v8, this has moved into the [MassTransit.StateMachineVisualizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.StateMachineVisualizer) NuGet package.

And the unit test is [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/d75201a6c6cb114814e32635fefcff9ac79d1df5/tests/MassTransit.Tests/SagaStateMachineTests/Automatonymous/Visualizer_Specs.cs#L19).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I searched for!

Comment: in case someone else stumbles here, the updated link is https://github.com/MassTransit/Automatonymous/blob/bc03484ac2cef256c711817569260a22d454522c/tests/Automatonymous.Tests/Visualizer_Specs.cs